# How can I get C++ to prefer converting char* to string_view instead of bool?

Tags: c++, c++17, implicit-conversion

I have a simple program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

class C {
  public:
    void print(std::string_view v) { std::cout << "string_view: " << v << std::endl; }
    void print(bool b) { std::cout << "bool: " << b << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  C c;
  c.print("foo");
}
```

When I run it, it prints `bool: 1`

How can I get C++ to prefer the `string_view` implicit conversion instead of the `bool` implicit conversion?

Comment: you should add a 3rd overload: `print(const char*)` that constructs `string_view` and calls `print()` with it.

Comment: Yeah this was just an example, my actual program has lots of types and almost everything in c++ is convertible to bool

Comment: What I actually want is something like "try every other implicit cast first, then try `bool` if nothing else works".

Comment: Here's a link that demonstrates some techniques such as ` std::enable_if ` -- https://www.foonathan.net/2015/10/overload-resolution-1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn the `string_view` overload into a template function, and add a constraint to it so that it has a higher preference than the `bool` overload when it receives a type that can be converted to `string_view`.

```
#include <string_view>

class C {
  public:
    template<class T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<const T&, std::string_view>>
    print(const T& v) { std::cout << "string_view: " << std::string_view(v) << std::endl; }
    void print(bool b) { std::cout << "bool: " << b << std::endl; }
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/fP46xTaPa)

Comment: Why does adding the constraint give it a higher preference?

Comment: The deduced type of `T` is actually a string literal type, since there is no implicit conversion involved, it has a higher priority. The purpose of `enable_if` is to constrain this function to only accept types that can be converted to `string_view`, such as `const char*` or `string_view`.